# Bootstrap DatePicker - Validate Date

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I have a bootstrap datepicker set up such that the `startDate = '1/1/1990'`, but if the user enters the date manually in the text box to something such as `1/1/201` (likely mistype of `1/1/2014`), the date is just blanked out when they change focus. Is there a way such that if they attempt to leave the field with an invalid date that instead of having a blank field that I can specify something like today's date, or even change the background color and not allow for the user to leave that field?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: use _onChange_ event handler on date input to check your date after it was changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out that I can simply detect when the value of the date has been set to '' and go from there with what I want to change:

```
$('#StartDate').change(function()
{
    if (this.value === '')
    {
        alert('Start date is now set to empty string, do work here');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also set the date field to readonly, in this way user can only select correct date format from datepicker.

example:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_readonly.asp

Comment: I like this idea... It also prevents the user typing in any random text and having to validate that

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jquery validation plugin for the color, showing msg for the invalid date. And in that case for validating the date value with present date you have to add a custom validation method to it like :-

```
           $.validator.addMethod("presentDate", function(value, element) {

                if(new Date(value).getTime() >= new Date().getTime()){
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            });
```